# Python sqlite query based on logged username

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

*I am struggling to understand why I cannot get the expected result from my query.
I am using flask with SQLite and can easily return the username to the webpage with the*  **"userlogin = session['username']"**
*What i am trying to get is to query the database based on the username of the logged user in order to only show information related to this specific user.*
**mytable** *is configured with username column used for the filter.*

```
@app.route('/dashboard') 
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
    from functions.sqlquery import sql_query
    userlogin = session['username']
    results = sql_query('''SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username IS "userlogin"''')
    return render_template('dashboard.html', results=results)
```

**sql_query.py**

```
def sql_query(query):
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(query)
   rows = cur.fetchall()
   return rows
```

Comment: you’re not passing the username variable properly into your statement.

Comment: what should I correct to pass it correctly?

Comment: `results = sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username = {userlogin}")`

Comment: still getting error but I just got a working suggestion from jignatius many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql query isn't correct. You use should `=` instead of `IS`.

I would recommend making the following changes:

1) use a parameterised query to avoid sql injection attacks. So pass the parameters to `sql_query()` as a tuple:

```
def sql_query(query, params):
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(query, params)
   rows = cur.fetchall()
   return rows
```

2) change the call to `sql_query`

```
results = sql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username = ?", (userlogin,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
results = sql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username IS "+userlogin)
```

Although above code is also a bad practice from security point of view

I guess what you are expecting from your query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE username IS (whatever session['username'] returns)
```

but what your code really translates into is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE username IS "userlogin"
```

(whatever you wrote AS IT IS)

If I am not mistaken, in php you can get away with `$variableName` even inside string but in python it does not work like that

*OR I AM COMPLETELY MISSING SOMETHING BECAUSE I DON'T KNOW FLASK AND SQLITE THAT MUCH AND I USUALLY USE PYTHON2.7*

Comment: thanks, I have tried but got some errors, using both ways,     sqlite3.OperationalError: near "session": syntax error